# HTML - How to keep semantically correct <article> placement with scattered containers?

Tags: css, html

I'm building a HTML document that is supposed to be semantically correct. Therefore, `<aside>` that is related to the website (i.e. sidebar) should be placed outside `<article>` and `<aside>` related directly to the article (if any) should be placed inside `<article>`.

That's not a problem with the left layout on my image because this will work:

```
<article>article</article>
<aside>sideabr</aside>

.article, .aside { float: left; }
.article { width: 70%; }
.aside { width: 30%; }
```

But what if main `<h1>` of the article is supposed to be placed above the article and the sidebar? I can't just nest the article and the sidebar in `<article>` because the sidebar is not a side note in the article. And I can't nest header + paragraphs in `<article>` because the sidebar will not align to paragraphs but to the header like in the first case.

[image]

Any idea how the HTML structure of such document should look like?

Most websites good as reference use the left version: http://twentytwelvedemo.wordpress.com/about-2/ so I can't find anything reliable to learn from.

This is how it should look like technically but can this be done in HTML at all?:

[image]

Comment: Your desired structure suggests to me that the aside belongs to the article.  There's not really a good way to do this with an unpredictable text element.

Comment: @cimmanon That's right - red means that it belongs to the article but I want to avoid this because it really isn't a part of the article. Maybe I should omit `<h1>` and not put it inside `<article>`? That's the best that comes to my mind.

Comment: This would be the aside of a parent section, for example. But then a heading that spans both its article and the aside of parent section would be misleading

Comment: Make the `article` 70% wide, let the `header` overflow-x and position the `aside` relatively

Comment: Hello, another way using float elements and display so it clears : easy if no borders: http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/lKEeg , tricky with borders : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/zctaE  | header included in article like sketch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By separating `article` in two: heading and content (just a `div`) and then floating this content, you can achieve the desired effect.

`aside` may be floating too (you must then set a width) or be set to `overflow: hidden`.

You can't add a clearfix on `article` (or `aside` will stay below) so you've to put it on parent (here `section`). Same for background if it must have one.

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BAjLr

**CSS**

```
section {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: tomato;
}
/* clearfix */
section:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: left;
}

/* article */
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
article .content {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

/* aside of section */
aside {
  overflow: hidden;    
  color: white;
  background-color: darkslateblue;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section>
  <article>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id laudantium beatae quae recusandae!</h1>
    <div class="content">
      <p>article Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt repudiandae nam commodi iusto ullam neque aliquam ut numquam. Cumque ut tempora consectetur quam velit ad incidunt necessitatibus saepe eos exercitationem.</p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <aside>
    <h2>sidebar</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam quae</p>
  </aside>
</section>
```

Comment: Great, that works! I think that many people create similar layouts but most aren't yet transferred to HTML5 so this question and answer should be helpful to them. Thanks!

Comment: @FelipeAls , if you float header and resize it, the layout via display:table can do the clearing ;) http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/lKEeg